# Update Row with Previous Row

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following table:

[image]

I am trying to write an update that fills the zeros with previous value greater than zero

[image]

I have tried with the following querys without success

1.

```
With cte As
(
    SELECT [ID], [Q_G_R_BUOM], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID] Asc) AS RN
    FROM [Testing_Lag]
)
update cte set [Q_G_R_BUOM]=iif([Q_G_R_BUOM]>0,[Q_G_R_BUOM],(SELECT [Q_G_R_BUOM] FROM cte WHERE [ID]=[ID]-1))
```

2. 

```
With cte As
(
    SELECT [ID], [Q_G_R_BUOM], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID] Asc) AS RN
    FROM [Testing_Lag]
)
update cte set [Q_G_R_BUOM]=iif([Q_G_R_BUOM]>0,[Q_G_R_BUOM],(Lag([Q_G_R_BUOM], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [ID] ASC)))
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method in SQL Server uses an updatable CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select tl.*,
             max(Q_G_R_BUOM) over (partition by grp) as imputed_Q_G_R_BUOM
      from (select tl.*,
                   sum(case when Q_G_R_BUOM <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
            from testing_lag tl
           ) tl
     ) 
update toupdate
    set Q_G_R_BUOM = imputed_Q_G_R_BUOM
    where Q_G_R_BUOM = 0;
```

This assigns a grouping to each row based on the number number of non-zero values up to that row.  It then "spreads" that value over the entire group.

An alternative method uses `apply`:

```
update tl
    set q_g_r_buom = tl2.q_g_r_buom
    from test_lag tl cross apply
         (select top (1) tl2.*
          from test_lag tl2
          where tl2.q_g_r_buom <> 0 and
                tl2.id < tl.id
          order by tl2.id
         ) tl2
    where tl.q_g_r_buom = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, comment that the update must be based on the Asc ID, does this query work in this way?

Comment: @Laureanorubioaguilar . . . Both these answers depend on the `id` to define the ordering of the table.  Both take the "preceding" non-`0` value based on the id.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
--DROP TABLE #C
CREATE TABLE #C (ID INT, Q_G_R_BUOM INT)
INSERT INTO #C values(1, 1805)
INSERT INTO #C values(2, 0)
INSERT INTO #C values(3, 0)
INSERT INTO #C values(4, 4732)
INSERT INTO #C values(5, 0)
INSERT INTO #C values(6, 0)

select * from #c
```

[image]

If you have nulls in your table, the solution would be a bit different.

```
SELECT ID,CASE WHEN Q_G_R_BUOM >0
            THEN Q_G_R_BUOM
            ELSE (SELECT max(Q_G_R_BUOM)
                  FROM #C
                  WHERE ID <= t.ID)
       END AS X
FROM #C t
```

[image]

```
DROP TABLE #C
CREATE TABLE #C (ID INT, Q_G_R_BUOM INT)
INSERT INTO #C values(1, 1805)
INSERT INTO #C values(2, null)
INSERT INTO #C values(3, null)
INSERT INTO #C values(4, 4732)
INSERT INTO #C values(5, null)
INSERT INTO #C values(6, null)

select * from #c
```

[image]

```
SELECT ID,
COALESCE(Q_G_R_BUOM,
MAX(COALESCE(Q_G_R_BUOM,'')) OVER (ORDER BY ID  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND  1 PRECEDING)) AS Name
FROM #c
```

[image]